# Compilation Error after deoplyment. Doesn't recognize 'Theme' attribute

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction, themes

My local copy works fine, then I publish the website and I get this error.

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Theme' is not a member of 'ASP.invoice_aspx'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ page title="Invoice" language="VB" masterpagefile="~/MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="Invoice, App_Web_1d5eb-af" theme="Default" %>
>
> Line 2:
>
> Line 3:  `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" Runat="Server">`
>
> Source File: C:\Inetpub\eSolutions_xyAMP_DEV\Invoice.aspx    Line: 1

What is going on here?

HTML SOURCE

```
<%@ Page Title="Invoice" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Invoice.aspx.vb" Inherits="Invoice" Theme="Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <table style="width:100%;">    
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:panel id="pnl"   runat="server"
                Width="992px" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                <asp:Button id="btnPrepareInvoice" runat="server"   Text="Trial Invoice"  ></asp:Button>
                <asp:Button id="btnFinalize" runat="server"   Text="Final Invoice"   ></asp:Button>
                </asp:panel>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table width="100%"> 
        <tr>
        <td     class="Subhdr" align="center" >
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" Cssclass="ScreenHdr"  runat="server" Font-Bold="True"  
            Font-Size="Medium"   Height="24px" 
                  Width="221px">Issued Contracts</asp:Label>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <asp:datagrid id="dgrContracts"  
                runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center"  BorderColor="#C0C0FF" 
        ForeColor="Blue" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px" 
        BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Arial"
                  ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanged="IssueDataGrid_Page" 
        OnSortCommand="IssueDataGrid_Sort" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="2" 
        GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowSorting="True" OnItemCommand="IssueDataGrid_Command" Width="100%">
                <FooterStyle Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"></FooterStyle>
                <SelectedItemStyle Wrap="False" BackColor="#E0E0E0"></SelectedItemStyle>
                <EditItemStyle Wrap="False"></EditItemStyle>
                <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" Height="18px"
                    BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#0000C0" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#C0C0FF" VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    ></AlternatingItemStyle>
                <ItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    Height="18px" ForeColor="#0000C0" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    Height="18px" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Blue"></HeaderStyle>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button id="btnSelect" runat="server" Width="13px" BackColor="Yellow" ForeColor="White"
                                Height="13px" CommandName="Select"></asp:Button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MBI_Selected"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CUST_CombinedNumber" SortExpression="CUST_CombinedNumber" HeaderText="Number">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CUST_Name" SortExpression="CUST_Name" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="110px" />
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DisplayDate" SortExpression="MBI_Date" HeaderText="Effective">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="80px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="VEHL_Year" HeaderText="Year">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DisplayMake" HeaderText="Make">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="VEHL_Model" HeaderText="Model">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="120px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MBI_PlanCode" HeaderText="Plan">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DisplayExchangePrice" HeaderText="Exch">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MBI_DlrCost" HeaderText="Cost" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle VerticalAlign="Top" NextPageText="&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;" Height="18px" PrevPageText="&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;"
                    HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Blue" Wrap="False"></PagerStyle>
            </asp:datagrid>

              <table width="100%"> 
        <tr>
        <td     class="Subhdr" align="center" >
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Cssclass="ScreenHdr"  runat="server" Font-Bold="True"  
            Font-Size="Medium"   Height="24px" 
                  Width="221px">Cancelled Contracts</asp:Label>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>

             <asp:datagrid id="dgrCancels"  
                runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center"   BorderColor="#C0C0FF" 
        ForeColor="Blue" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px" 
        BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Arial"  PageSize="5" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanged="CancelDataGrid_Page"
                OnSortCommand="CancelDataGrid_Sort" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="2" 
        GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
        OnItemCommand="CancelDataGrid_Command" Width="100%">
                <FooterStyle Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"></FooterStyle>
                <SelectedItemStyle Wrap="False" BackColor="#E0E0E0"></SelectedItemStyle>
                <EditItemStyle Wrap="False"></EditItemStyle>
                <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" Height="18px"
                    BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#0000C0" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#C0C0FF" VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    ></AlternatingItemStyle>
                <ItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    Height="18px" ForeColor="#0000C0" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    Height="18px" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Blue"></HeaderStyle>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button id="btnCancelSelect" runat="server" Width="13px" BackColor="Yellow" ForeColor="White"
                                Height="13px" CommandName="Select"></asp:Button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="CNCL_ID">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="0px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CNCL_Selected"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CUST_CombinedNumber" SortExpression="CUST_CombinedNumber" HeaderText="Number">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CUST_Name" SortExpression="CUST_Name" HeaderText="Name">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DisplayIssueDate" SortExpression="MBI_Date" HeaderText="Effective">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="80px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DisplayCancelDate" HeaderText="Cancel">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="80px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MBI_Miles" HeaderText="Effective">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CNCL_CancelMiles" HeaderText="Cancel">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MBI_Price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="40px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CNCL_CalculatedNetRefund" HeaderText="Price Refund" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="40px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MBI_DlrCost" HeaderText="Cost" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="40px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CNCL_CalculatedNetAdminRefund" HeaderText="Cost Refund" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="40px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle VerticalAlign="Top" NextPageText="&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;" Height="18px" PrevPageText="&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;"
                    HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Blue" Wrap="False"></PagerStyle>
            </asp:datagrid>
              <asp:Label ID="Errormsg" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC0000"  ></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured my problem here. I had a class named "Invoice" on my dbml as well as a page named "Invoice.aspx". This is a WebSite Project as opposed to a WebApplication so .net was correct in saying "Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Theme' is not a member of 'ASP.invoice_aspx'." blah blah. I wonder why this doesn't show up locally. This site was working fine on my local box, this was showing up after publishing the site to a server. Anyways, this is now working. I just renamed the aspx page and repubbed. <~~if thats a word. lol

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1):

Go into the property pages of the deployment project.  Under the Compilation tab, uncheck the option "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable".  This resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this one before, but I would start by double checking the version setting on virtual directory or website to make sure it is targeting the correct runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://arjansworld.blogspot.com/2006/11/aspnet-20-tip-theme-is-not-member-of.html

Can you put the HTML code up here to let us take a look?  Are you sure you cleaned all old DLL's out of the directory you deployed to?

Comment: Added the source, yes I cleared out the BIN on the server prior to publish

Comment: Do you have anything in your web.config that references theme?  Do you have it set to use fixed naming?

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks for you help. It was a duplicate class name. "invoice" already existed on my LinqToSQL dbml file. I renamed the file and everything works ok. It was not 'Theme' relevant after all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This has nothing to do with Themes. Check duplicate DLLS in your bin folder. You could remove the

> ', App_Web_1d5eb-af'

part of your inherit statement. But the issue is a duplicate library in the bin folder, As soon as you identify and delete/move them the error will go away. If not delete them all and rebuild, some remaining legacy dll could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found the solution [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1000979.aspx?BC30456+Theme+is+not+a+member+of+ASP+default_aspx+).

The problem happens when there are 2 partial classes with the same name in the project. In my case, I had renamed `Home.aspx.vb` to `Home-OLD.aspx.vb` and replaced it with another page named `Home.aspx` (and codebehind file). The problem is that I didn't rename the class within `Home-OLD.aspx.vb` so I had 2 classes named `Home` in the project.

I ended up commenting out the old `Home-OLD.aspx` and `Home-OLD.aspx.vb` code for now and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have validated you don't have a class name collision and you are using a dynamic compilation website, you may need to clear out the Temp ASP files. Review the full path of the error to the .dll and delete the folder it is contained in.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ [your site] \ [random number] \ [your site dlls]

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ [your site] \ [random number] \ [your site dlls]